# Can not using join() in multi thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some problem about multithread. My program is below:

```
...
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
   new Thread(){
       @Overried
       public void run(){
           <do something level 1>

           <do something level 2>
       }
   }.start;
}
<do something level 3>
...
```

I hope main thread only executes [do something level 3] after all 10 thread finished [do something level 2]. And do not have any thread execute [do something level 2] before the event which all child-thread finished [do something level 1] occurs.

Comment: 'Not auccessful' is not an adequate problem description.

Answer (score 3):

You should keep references to the threads you started in order to call `join` on them.

To achieve the first thing, you can do:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
   threads[i] = new Thread(){
       // ...
   };
   threads[i].start();
}
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
   threads[i].join();
}
```

For the second one, you should probably use `wait` in the main thread and `notify` in the child threads (after finishing task one) to signal the end of the first part, then `wait` on the child threads and `notifyAll` on the main thread to signal that all thread accomplished first part.

Comment: im a bit rusty on the wait/notify mechanism but if the main thread `wait`s on something then a single `notify` will wake it up and if ti does a `notifyAll` it will signal all child threads waiting by that time. Furthermore child threads that havent quite reached the wait state at that time will never be woken up

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you break up `[do level 1]` and `[do level 2]` in two blocks.

something like

```
...

for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
   new Thread(){
       public void run(){
           <do something level 1>
       }
   }.start;
}

**join** 

for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
   new Thread(){
       public void run(){
           <do something level 2>
       }
   }.start;
}


<do something level 3>
...
```

rather than working with `wait` \ `notify` with counters in main thread. may be just because im not comfortable with those but i believe it makes things unnecessarily complex and you will almost certainly run into race conditions.

Further more i suggest you use the `ExecutorService` abstraction rather than working with `Thread`s. They eliminate the need to work at lowest level, and are much configurable and powerful too. Once you get used to them they are also a lot simpler to understand.

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        final int w = i;
        service.execute(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                long wait = (long) (Math.random() * 1000);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(wait);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println(w + "LEVEL 1 done " + wait);

            }
        });
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    System.out.println("all level 1 done");

    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        final int w = i;
        service.execute(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                long wait = (long) (Math.random() * 1000);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(wait);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println(w + "LEVEL 2 done " + wait);

            }
        });
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    System.out.println("all done");
```